# graph db modelling - Node vs Property on a node or edge

Tags: database, graph, azure-cosmosdb

Understand that this is more of a design question and could not find a definitive guideline and we are new on this graph db journey.

Question : We are trying to model a network in graph db and are confused on placing certain elements as node or as an property of an edge. So we have 2 network nodes say A and B. There is a schedule for things to move from A and B . Now should this schedule be a node by itself or is it best placed as a property of the edge connecting A and B.

And yes we would want to query on this schedule though always in context of the nodes. 
DB Used : Cosmos 
Number of nodes : Maximum of a million

Comment: It's hard to say which way is more efficient without knowing your specific business logic data process.

Comment: I will try an explain the logic : We would like to query for a full path a product will traverse through and would want to know the paths possible as well as the lead times for the path. The lead times are a attribute of edge between nodes and a particular edge is active only on select days.   So the path can be A-> B -> C -> D where as C-> D is possible only on mon, wed and thursday and similarly for other nodes. Based on the schedule and leadtime across nodes we will have to know the overall lead time for the particular product. Hope it helps to understand the problem we want to solve